# How to view diagram map for java in visual studio?

Tags: java, visual-studio

I found this blog:
https://csharp.2000things.com/2013/01/11/756-viewing-a-class-diagram-in-visual-studio-2012/ .
It is about viewing diagram map for C# in Visual Studio.
But I use coding Java in Visual Studio.
How can I view diagram like that ? Is it possible ?

Comment: Welcome on SO. You must do efforts to present your messages in a clearer form. To go to a new line, write two blanks and return. Please, put capital letters where it is required : Java, Visual Studio, C#, I. Please, use verbs as required: "viewing" instead of "view" (the title in your link is "Viewing a Class Diagram in Visual Studio 2012"), "Is it" and not "it is", "It is about viewing" and not "it about view".

Comment: and is it possible? and is it possible with any project code?

Comment: is diagram visualize just 1 file click on it or all of file in project?

Comment: how to save diagram file,(not image)?

Comment: Excuse me to be unable to answer to your question. I was lead by chance to edit your post by clicking inquisitively on the "review" button at the top of the page. But I don't know Java, nor Visual Studio. - And on the points on which I was able to say something (for example: capital letters), you don't care of.